# Only admin can access event registration page

Tags: civievent

I've created a view with a block of upcoming civicrm events with links to the online registration pages. Only the administrator can get to the registration page. Anonymous and authorized users get this message:

"Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
XML data could not be loaded. Make sure you specified the correct path.

Return to home page."

Anonymous and authorized users have permission for
CiviEvent:register for events, CiviEvent:view event info , CiviCRM:access all custom data.

The CiviEvent is setup to allow online registration.

Comment: No longer getting that message. Now getting"The requested Profile (gid=12) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance."

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps in the original comment you might want to do first but this link has the solution that worked for a few people.   https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=23855.msg100253#msg100253

Try:

rm -rf sites/all/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/

CiviCRM will rebuild the ConfigAndLog folder.

-Steve

Comment: The fix you link to refers to the original error message but, as I mentioned, that is no longer the issue. Anonymous users are getting a different message (see my comment above). Also, that error only occurs when using Firefox. Registration works fine using Chrome, Safari, or Opera.